# filterOptions in Autocomplete does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, autocomplete

I have this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auto-complete-eg-twbtvt?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts)

When I click + I can filter a State and show state name correctly.
When I click + again to add the State , the filter does not work.

I have this filter code:

```
this.filteredStates = this.myform.controls['products_id'].valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(state =>  this._filterStates(state))
  );
```

Any Idea please?

Comment: can you explain little more

Comment: I have a problem filter in autocomplete. In first, I click `Add Item` and search for o state. Search works good. In second I want to add more Item, click `Add Item` search but the search doesn't work. This problem I illustrate in this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auto-complete-eg-qmu7cn?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.html

Comment: Have you any idea please?

Comment: Can you ask any idea please? I want really your help!

Comment: wait i will explain

Comment: if you try to console inside your _filterStates(value) method. you will see the value changes are returning array of data so your filter is not working

Comment: Yes I know this. How to solution this problem?

Comment: use pipe instead of doing this way

Comment: Hello, I try a pipe like you say, but I have a error. Can you see this post please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811971/error-ts2322-type-observablestring-is-not-assignable-to-type-observable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution but it's working.

So the problem is that after you add more fields the value of the form array starts to look like this: `["3", "P"]` and your filter function stops working.

So in case you want to keep your approach with tracking form values as Observable I've made a custom pipe that does the actual filtering.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform<T>(value: string, list: T[], field: string, idx: number): T[] { 
    const filterValue = value[idx] ? value[idx].toString().toLowerCase() : '';
    return list.filter(state => state[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

}
```

Then instead of

`*ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async`

you use the pipe

`*ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async | myPipe: states : 'products_name': i"`

It's more or less generic, so it takes your list of states and a field to search in.

Also in your component replace

```
   this.filteredStates = this.myform.controls['products_id'].valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(state =>  this._filterStates(state))
  );
```

with

```
   this.filteredStates = this.myform.controls['products_id'].valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(['']),
  );
```

So this way we just use value changes as Observable.
Obviously some variables should be renamed.

And that's it. Please comment if it's not working and I missed to add something.

Oh, and yes - don't forget to add custom pipe to your AppModule declarations

```
import { MyPipe } from './app/my-pipe.pipe';
...
declarations: [
    AutocompleteOverviewExample,
    MyPipe
],
```

Comment: I try it but in my code show this error: `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<State[]>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'State[]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'State'.`

Comment: Made a StackBlitz with this - looks working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auto-complete-eg-kccsao

Comment: Show error in this  `filteredStates: Observable<State[]>;`

Comment: Have you any idea, why for me doesn't work your demo?