# error TS2322: Type 'Observable<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Sensors[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

This error:

> error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'. Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type
>   'Sensors[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Sensors'.

show in this Typescript Code:

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

    filteredSensors: Observable<Sensors[]>;

        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private ws: SensorService
            ) {
                this.myform= new FormGroup({
                  'sensors_id': this.fb.array([], Validators.required),
                  'unit_price': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
                });

                    this.filteredSensors = this.myform.controls['sensors_id'].valueChanges
                  .pipe(
                    startWith(['']),
                  );
              }
        ngOnInit() {
           this.ws.getAllSensors().subscribe(
            sensors => {
            this.sensors = sensors
           }
         );
       }
```

In html I have this : `*ngFor="let sensor of filteredSensors | async | myPipe: sensors : 'sensor_serial': i"`

And I have this pipe:

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'myPipe'
    })
 export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform<T>(value: Sensors, list: T[], field: string, idx: number): T[] {
        const filterValue = value[idx] ? value[idx].toString().toLowerCase() : ''; //correct this line of as per Sensors object
        return list.filter(sensor => sensor[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
    }
}
```

Any idea please, how to solution this error?

Sensors.ts

```
export class Sensors {
    sensorType_id: number;
    sensortype_id: number;
    sensors_id: string;
    sensor_serial: string;
    active: number;
    sensordescription: string;
    unit_price: number;
    description: string;
    note: string;
    Sensor_id: number;
    default_price: number;
    client_id: string;
    client_name: String;

    constructor(obj: any) {

        this.sensorType_id = obj && obj.sensortype_id || obj.sensorType_id;
        this.sensortype_id = obj && obj.sensortype_id;
        this.client_id = obj && obj.client_id;
        this.sensor_serial = obj && obj.sensor_serial;
        this.sensors_id = obj && obj.sensors_id;
        this.active = obj && obj.active;
        this.sensordescription = obj && obj.sensordescription;
        this.unit_price = obj && obj.unit_price;
        this.description = obj && obj.description;
        this.note = obj && obj.note;
        this.Sensor_id = obj && obj.Sensor_id;
        this.default_price = obj && obj.default_price;
        this.client_name = obj && obj.client_name;
    }
}
```

and ws SensorService:

```
public getAllSensors(): Observable<Sensors[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.getAllSensors), {
        headers: headers
    })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let res = response.json();
            if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
                this.auth.logout();
                return false;
            } else {
                return res.StatusDescription.map(sensors => {
                    return new Sensors(sensors);
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: can you create stackblitz please

Comment: i have edited can you check the update stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyc4mf-ya6smp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is type issue in your `Pipe`. In Pipe, you are saying that it will operate on `String` however you are passing `Sensors`. So change the `argument` `type` of `Pipe` and make the changes in you business login inside the `Pipe`,

```
 @Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: string[], value: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    let array =  items.filter(item => item == value);
    return  items.filter(item => item == value);
  }
}
```

## in html

`*ngFor="let sensor of filteredSensors | async | myPipe: i"`

> Note : 'i' above is value by which filter will apply on.

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-on-array

Comment: In this part: `...sensor[field].toLowerCase().....` show `[ts] Type 'Sensors' cannot be used as an index type.
`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: In this part `if (!items) return [];` show `[tslint] if statements must be braced`

Comment: I change code like this `if (!items) {
            return [];
        } else {
            return items.filter(Sensors => Sensors[field] === value);
        }` but doesn't work

Comment: filter works good only in this: `export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform<T>(value: Sensors, list: T[], field: string, idx: number): T[] {
        const filterValue = value[idx] ? value[idx].toString().toLowerCase() : ''; //correct this line of as per Sensors object
        return list.filter(sensor => sensor[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
    }
}`

Comment: But in ts code, show again error `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Sensors[]>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Sensors[]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Sensors'.`

Comment: your `filteredSensors`  is the array of type String. Updated the answer as well.

Comment: Doesn't work! Show again this error: `error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Sensors[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Sensors'.`

Comment: Are you getting the same error ? Please look at this copy https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-on-array

Comment: Yes, is same error. I think that this error is in typescript code, not in pipe. Pipe works good.

Comment: Click on the error and check the line where it is showing the error.

Comment: Error show in this line: `this.filteredSensors = this.myform.controls['sensors_id'].valueChanges`

Comment: Now issue is not with Pipe. You have issue in component. Change this line `filteredSensors: Observable<Sensors[]>;` to `filteredSensors: Observable<string[]>;`

Comment: When I remove '' and write like this `this.filteredSensors = this.myform.controls['sensors_id'].valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith([]),
    );` error removed but filter doesn't work

Comment: this is solution `filteredSensors: Observable<Sensors[]>; to filteredSensors: Observable<string[]>` thank you!